# React Router error You should not use <Link> outside a <Router> when using Link before Return in Component when using Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, react-router-dom

My Application using
React v17.0.2
react-router-dom v5.2.0",
@ashvin27/react-datatable v1.5.3

So the datatable has built in features to download data into excel
But when i click the button it causes
this error
Error: Invariant failed: You should not use  outside a

Here is the codesandbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/link-outside-datatable-eo6d3

here is my Code
**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import AppRoutes from "./AppRoutes";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <Container>
      <AppRoutes />
    </Container>
    </>
  );
}
```

**AppRoutes.jsx**

```
import { Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Pages from "./Pages";

const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/">
                <Pages />
            </Route>
      </Switch>
    )
}

export default AppRoutes
```

**Tables.jsx**

```
import Tables from "./Tables"
import ShowData from "./ShowData";
import records from "./records.json"
import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { useState } from "react";

const Pages = () => {
    const { path } = useRouteMatch();
    const [data, setData] = useState("")
    const columns = [
        {
            key: "name",
            text: "Name",
            className: "name",
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            key: "address",
            text: "Address",
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            key: "action",
            text: "Action",
            cell: (record, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        <Link to={`/view/${index}`}>
                            <button
                                className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                                style={{marginRight: '5px'}}
                                onClick={setData(record)}>
                                    Show Data
                            </button>
                        </Link>
                    </>
                );
            }
        }
    ];

    return (
        <>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path={path}>
                <Tables records={records} columns={columns} />
            </Route>
            <Route exact path={`/view/:id`}>
                <ShowData data={data}/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
        </>
    )
}

export default Pages
```

**Tables.jsx**

```
import ReactDatatable from '@ashvin27/react-datatable';

const Tables = ({records,columns}) => {
    
    const config = {
        page_size: 10,
        length_menu: [10, 20, 50],
        show_filter: true,
        show_pagination: true,
        filename: "restaurents",
        button: {
            excel: true,
            print: true,
            csv: true
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <ReactDatatable
                config={config}
                records={records}
                columns={columns}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Tables
```

**ShowData.jsx**

```
const ShowData = ({data}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Data</h1>
            <h2>Name : {data.name}</h2>
            <h2>Addres : {data.address}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ShowData
```

The error was when i using this inside **Pages.jsx** . I can navigate to the ShowData Page, but i cant download to excel.

```
{
        key: "action",
        text: "Action",
        cell: (record, index) => {
            return (
                <>
                    <Link to={`/view/${index}`}>
                        <button
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                            style={{marginRight: '5px'}}
                            onClick={setData(record)}>
                                Show Data
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </>
            );
        }
    }
```

But if i give  i can download the files, but i can't navigate to the **"/view/${index}"**

```
{
    key: "action",
    text: "Action",
    cell: (record, index) => {
        return (
            <>
                <BrowserRouter>
                    <Link to={`/view/${index}`}>
                        <button
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                            style={{marginRight: '5px'}}
                            onClick={setData(record)}>
                                Show Data
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot
[image]
The Excel Download button is the right side of the search bar.

Do you guys have any solution?
Thank you before!

Comment: can you please create the example in codesandbox

Comment: Hello, Here my codesandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/link-outside-datatable-eo6d3